# Graph API errors that we cannot control

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are working on an automation that reaches out to Graph API on a schedule (every 5 minutes) and manipulates some worksheets.
Most of the times it works fine, but sporadically, we're running into a  errors coming from the API that we cannot control, here's the most frequent:

```
Status: 504
cannot POST /v1.0/me/drive/items/<docid>/workbook/createSession (504)
```

Is this a known issue? Or are we doing something wrong?

And sometimes, the error comes in a totally bizarre way, as html:

```
StatusError: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/> <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title> <style type="text/css"> <!-- body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;} fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF; background-color:#555555;} #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} --> </style> </head> <body> <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div> <div id="content"> <div class="content-container"><fieldset> <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2> <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3> </fieldset></div> </div> </body> </html> at s (/var/task/dist/index.js:1:8872) at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7) name: 'StatusError', status: 404, code: 'UnknownError', agent: 'cannot POST /v1.0/me/drive/items/01MFBSIOQF7YVAPATDUJEI2LJAMXXGERX3/workbook/createSession (404)' }
```

Comment: do you retry in that situation? does the error reoccur in those situations?  We retry most of our requests incase it is something transient in graph that is failing.

Comment: That's the only way to deal with this I can think of too. Do you retry right away? And if it still fails - how many times do you try before giving up?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm getting the same with a long path on the following end point GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path}

Comment: I don't believe much changed there, right now we're just retrying and hoping that it works the next time.